# jquery mobile and dynamic page content

Tags: django, stream, jquery-mobile

i have a jquery moblie frontend to a website running with django. i have a use case where something may take a long time to complete so i would like the user to see its progress as it happens; in my example it is a sequence of events and whether they are success/fail.

in the backend i have a `generator` object that spits out this information. it is wrapped around a `HttpResponse` object in order to fullfil the streaming aspect of the updates. a simple webpage (just html and body tags) demonstrates that it works as expected.

however, jquery mobile (at least by default) likes to load the entire page before displaying it.

i don't mind showing this output as a dialog.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to update my experience of this.

so in the end i spent most of my time scratching my head with jquery mobile. of course if i had rtfm'd beforehand i would have probably had a smaller headache out of it all! basically the ajax page updates were just plain annoying, so the important thing here would be to disable them using `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` on my html `form` - and, because of the way #'s are used, you will also want to add these tags to any pages that load up this page also (otherwise the multipage won't work properly).

i then created a multipage jqm page and link to it via my submit button (in my case with `data-rel="dialog"`), with the second page with an empty `iframe`; i set the form `target` to this iframe and voila! it works! the streaming result from the form submission shows up as it should.

so to sum it up:

- django HttpResponse is returned, where its argument is a generator object. this enables the streaming nature of the output.
- create the jqm page:

  ```
  <div id="main" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
      <form id="myform" method="post" target="response-iframe" action="***django generator page***" data-ajax="false">
        ...
        <a id="submit-button" href="#secondary" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-theme="e">Submit</a>
        <script>
        $('#submit-button').live( 'click', function(){
            $('#port-form').submit()
          })
        </script>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="secondary" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
      <iframe id="response-iframe"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can poll Django for progress updates using usual AJAX requests.

It don't solve the jquery mobile and long polling problem, but it gives you flexibility needed to put your long running task away from the frontend and into the backend (for example using Celery).

To maintain performance I recommend updating status from the long running task to a memcached instance.

In your view just fetch the progress and return i.e.  which will fire the dialog box or update some div. Better yet - just the results.